# updating manifest.json file doesn't change lighthouse report errors react native

Tags: react-native, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm trying to make the desktop version of a react-native app a PWA.
I keep encountering the same report:
[lighthouse report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0slA5.png)

```
{
  "short_name": "test",
  "name": "test",
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon/favicon-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose":"any"
    }
    ,{
      "src": "favicon/favicon-144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose":"any"
    }
  ],
  "app":{
    "urls": [
      "http://localhost:19006/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://localhost:19006/"
    }
  },
  "loading":"loading_screen.gif",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#1E88B5",
  "background_color": "#f2f7fc",
  "scope": "/"
}
```

This is the root directory:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CvsR.png)

Any feedback would be appreciated!

I tried changing the value to the "src" property for the icons, but the changes are not reflected in the lighthouse report. I also cleared the browser cache.
P.S: other checks in the lighthouse report pass but not the installability one.

Answer (score -1):

Are you re-creating a production build (usually with `npm run build`) each time you update the manifest.json file?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).